# Suggestion about cable parallel digital

Tags: adc

I have a adc [AD7829](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad7829-1.pdf) which is parallel 8 bits digital outputs.

I consider using cable to transfer digital (out) data.

Circuit likes:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Board 1
------------------------------------------------------------
| [I/V Converter] -> [Analog Buf] -> [ADC]->[Digital Buf]  |
------------------------------------------------------------
                                                ||
                                         Parallel Cable ~3M
                                                ||
------------------------------------------------------------
Board 2                                         ||
------------------------------------------------------------
|                      [PC Host] <- [FPGA]<-[Digital Buf]  |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I read [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/163468/spi-max-distance)

Long distance(>2M) doesn't seems to SPI/I2C... etc. IC-IC protocol.

So I thought maybe `Parallel Cable` not is good choice for transfer with cable.

Should I add **Serder** IC convert 8bits parallel signal to LVDS with clock?

Or does any good others suggestion for this circiut?

Many thanks!

### Edit

#### Add SPEC

- Before analog input: 8 channels photodiode
- Analog input: Pulse, R/F time ~6us
- I/V converter: OPA192

I think that 1Mbps sample rate ADC should be enough.

Comment: We don't know what you want to do and how fast. Why not open up the specs and numbers to have an idea what to answer. I2C can go multiple meters if properly designed, albeit with compromise on speed

Comment: Why can't the A2D be on board 2? Which serdes are you considering?

Comment: Hi @Justme: Sorry, I'll add detailed spec.

Comment: Hi @Andyaka: You means pass signal with analog? AFAIK, digital signal should be better for transfer than analog signal

Comment: @curlywei unjustified. When we transmit radio, we use analogue radio methods and that works from Pluto to earth. Designed properly, analogue over 3 metres compared to 8 bits of parallel data is likely to be just as reliable if not more.

Comment: Hi @Andyaka: Thanks your suggestion. Yes, VGA is a good instance, even VGA is just 3 analog channels.